# Can java cache strike when the thread is not put to sleep manually?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, caching

To make my problem/question easier to understand, I'll put it in a bullet list:

- Have a volatile array.
- Data is set to this array from multiple threads but the threads NEVER run at  the same time.
- I have a code like that in one of the threads (which don't execute in parallel):

  `{
      myArray[0] = myData;
      sleep(1);
      doSomething(myArray[0]);
   }`
- Now it sometimes (fairly well reproducible) happens that `doSomething()` does NOT receive `myData` but instead some data set once in another thread!

I am fairly sure that there's the Java caching mechanism striking here because even if the array is volatile, it's elements can stupidly not be made volatile.

This code section is very speed critical thus I would really want to avoid using `AtomicReferenceArray` as I also don't need atomic functionality.

However it was only a coincidence (debugging purpose) that I had sleep() just in there. It is not needed.

BUT I know that the CPU or Windows will randomly switch/sleep threads anyways. So does that mean that also without `sleep()`, I could run into this issue on long term and with bad luck?
It did not happen within ~20 minutes of testing time at least.
So does that mean that the JVM (and its caching) works differently if the CPU switches its thread and I don't make it sleep myself?

If the former is the case, does anyone have some suggestion how to avoid this problem?

Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that Threads doesn't run in parallel. Could you write the 3 line of code in synchronized block?

As all the variables which are in synchronized block, refresh the value from the main memory. So you will get an most recent updated value.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Unfortunately no change in behavior... Are you sure that this refresh actually applies to elements inside of arrays too? I will export the crucial parts into a separate project, but am fairly sure that they do not run in parallel since in fact the initial set is only called a single time.

Comment: Argh, okey, nevermind all this q__q It was a completely stupid bug as I had a function working through ~3 functions on this array called inside a hover-event of JavaFX (which runs on its own thread). Damn, I was almost about to get suspicious that the error always appeared when I was playing with the GUI... Oh well, easily 3 hours wasted... Thanks very much for taking your time and trying to help!